# What can I use as an alternative for an underwriter's knot?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I want to hang a vertical pendant, but what do I do to prevent the wire from pulling through?  The vertical cord is a hard nylon that can carry the vertical load of the pendant, and the hole in the pendant is small enough for only the wire to pass through. If I make an underwriter's knot, the wire will not slip through and the pendant will hold.

But what is an alternative for this knot, as making it from the hard cord is rather difficult?

Comment: One of those times where some pictures of the fixture and cable would change a W-A-G into a useful answer. I've seen crimp collars used for this when the cord is sufficiently tough.

Comment: Is this a light pendant and the cord contains the electrical wires?  I understood that from the underwriters knot reference.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a fairly lightweight fixture, you could try a zip tie or two around the cord.  This may not work depending on how hard the cord is and how heavy the lamp is.  But I have used them with light weight pendants and cords that had some flex so the zip tie could squish the sheath a bit to keep it from slipping.

[image: Zip tie]

Another option, if there is enough space, is to use a [Waterproof Cable Gland](http://www.adafruit.com/products/762) they tighten onto the cord and depending on the cord material may not slip.  But there may not be enough space for one.  I seem to recall having a pendant light once that had something like this built into it to allow the height to be adjusted.